# Cannot close form opened on a separate thread

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that opens a secondary form like this:

```
var progressForm = new ProgressForm();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    progressForm.ShowDialog();
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

I also have an extension method to close the form:

```
private static void CloseForm(this Form formToClose)
{
    if (formToClose != null)
    {
        formToClose.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { formToClose.Close(); });
    }
}

public static void DoSomething(Form formToClose = null)
{
    formToClose.CloseForm();
}
```

But the form is not being closed.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can't trick the runtime into violating the `no UI modifications from other threads` rule. In fact, there's no other thread - `Task..StartNew(..TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())` will run the task on the *current*, UI thread. The code you tried will probably deadlock the application

Comment: If you want to report progress from a background task use the [Progress< T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=net-5.0) class. Check [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/). The `ProgressForm` only needs to handle the progress event. It doesn't need to be on a separate thread itself

Comment: sorry, but where is the call to `DoSomething` ?

Comment: @MongZhu The call is on the first form.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I originally had only `formToClose.Close()` but even this wasn't closing the form.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono [Form.Close()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?view=net-5.0) works. That's a fact. It's a 20-year old method, if it had bugs people would notice. If it fails, it's because the *form* somehow cancels closing, or there's an exception due to the cross-thread access attempt. The problem starts with `Task.Factory.StartNew`. You don't need these extension methods at all.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have an `AggregrateException` being thrown. So I want to first close the progress form and then open an error form (in `DoSomething`) Is there a way to close the progress form just the same?

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Could you share some codes more to close the Form?
DoSomething

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono btw `ShowDialog()` opens a modal form and blocks until the dialog closes. If you *don't* want a blocking modal form, use `Show`, not `ShowDialog`. You can't use `Task..StartNew` or `Task.Run` to make a modal form behave like a modeless form

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono `I have an AggregrateException being thrown` because you're trying to violate threading rules. Again, this code will never work. Besides, why are you even using `StartNew` instead of `async/await` and `Task.Run`? What is the rest of the code trying to do? Whatever it is, it's a lot easier to do it properly. Stephen Toub's examples in [Enabling Progress and Cancellation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) do exactly what you want - display a progress form, allowing for cancellation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah... I solved the problem with `async/await` and `IProgress`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No operating system allows a background thread to modify the UI. The question's code tries to do just that, and fails in various ways:

1. `Task.Factory.StartNew(...,TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` will run on the original thread, ie the UI thread. If the original thread isn't the UI, there will be errors.
2. `ShowDialog()` displays a modal form and *doesn't return* until the form closes. So what thread is going to run and try to close the form?
3. `Invoke` is a blocking call, so if the UI thread is already blocked, the call to `Close` will block indefinitely.

It looks like the question's code was an attempt to bypass those errors one by one:

1. Since `ShowDialog` blocks, use `Task..StartNew`.
2. This throws, so use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` to run on the UI thread.
3. Try to close the form from another thread

From the comments, it seems the code is already failing. Failing to close the form is just another symptom:

> I have an AggregrateException being thrown. So I want to first close the progress form and then open an error form (in DoSomething)

**Reporting progress**

Using progress and cancellation is a lot easier though. The article  [Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) shows how to do this using Windows Forms examples.

The [IProgres< T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=net-5.0) interface can be used to report progress from a background thread. The built-in implementation, [Progress< T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=net-5.0) will forward and handle report calls to the thread it was created on, eg the UI thread

Borrowing from the article's example, let's say there's a long-running `UploadPicturesAsync` async method:

```
async Task<int> UploadPicturesAsync(List<Image> imageList, IProgress<int> progress)
{
            int totalCount = imageList.Count;
            int processCount = await Task.Run<int>(() =>
            {
                int tempCount = 0;
                foreach (var image in imageList)
                {
                    //await the processing and uploading logic here
                    int processed = await UploadAndProcessAsync(image);
                    if (progress != null)
                    {
                        progress.Report((tempCount * 100 / totalCount));
                    }
                    tempCount++;
                }

                return tempCount;
            });
            return processCount;
}
```

Processing is done in a background task started with `Task.Run`. Every time a file is processed, `progress.Report` is called to pass a percentage. The method itself knows nothing about any progress bars or forms.

To display progress, let's assume we have a `ProgressForm` with a progress bar and a method `Report(int)` that sets the progress bar's value.

To start uploading *and* display progress, we display the progress form as *modeless* with `Show`, and call its `Report` method from the `Progress` class's handler :

```
private async void Start_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Display a modeless progress fom
    var progressForm=new ProgressForm();
    progressForm.Show();
    
    //Create the Progress class and pass `ProgressForm.Report` to it
    var progressIndicator = new Progress<int>(pct=>progressForm.Report(pct));
        
    try
    {
        //Execute the background operation
        int uploads=await UploadPicturesAsync(GenerateTestImages(), progressIndicator);

        //Close the form
        progressForm.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Finished!");
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
  
        progressForm.Close();        
        MessageBox.Show(exc.ToString(), "Failed!", 
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"if the UI thread is already blocked by ShowDialog, the call to Close will block indefinitely"_ -- that part isn't correct. The `ShowDialog()` method runs the message pump which allows `Invoke()` marshaling to be dispatched, as long as the thread is running normally (obviously, if there is something _else_ that is actually blocking the thread, it won't work, but `ShowDialog()` doesn't block a thread in the way that concerns `Invoke()`).

Comment: @PeterDuniho bad wording. The thread isn't blocked but the method that called `ShowDialog` is. That's probably why the OP tried to use a task to open the form. Then got a cross-thread exception and added `FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`. Then got `AggregateException` and so on ...

Comment: _"the method that called ShowDialog is"_ -- that's true, but I don't see how it would necessarily be material. Any thread, including the one that called `ShowDialog()` still _theoretically_ could call the `Invoke()` method to call the `Close()` method and close the dialog. It's just not true that _"...the call to Close will block indefinitely"_. There's no evidence in the code that was posted with the question that that would happen. If there are problems in the code that they _didn't_ post, it could...but nothing in the question itself suggests it would, so saying that it would is wrong.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I already removed `by ShowDialog`. And calling `Invoke` on a blocked UI thread is the classic deadlock example and the reason `InvokeAsync` should be used. This is a question where posting the correct code is a lot easier than explaining what's wrong with the current code, and I've already spent 1 (business) hour with this.

Comment: _"I already removed by ShowDialog"_ -- not when I'd posted my previous comment, you hadn't. _"posting the correct code is a lot easier than explaining what's wrong with the current code"_ -- well, given that no one but the question's author knows what the current code looks like, I certainly can't argue with that. But, _"I've already spent 1 (business) hour with this"_ ... I'm not sure how that's my concern or relevant to any of my comments.

Comment: @PeterDuniho it means you've crossed into pestering people for trying to help and *explain* what's wrong. It would be all too easy to just post some code, or just comment without answering. Can you post a better explanation? That would be helpful.

Comment: It's unfortunate that you view legitimate corrections to _your_ fallacious statements, "pestering".